# English and Arabic database ConnectionString in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string, multilingual

I'm working on a project that is in two languages English and Arabic.
The english version works fine, but I have problem in the connection string for Arabic Version.
In my project I have a sub folder (Ar) and it has the same project files as in English version, but different in culture (directions). Now I want to load the contect for Arabic version From the Arabic database. but it gives error in connection.

Here is the structure of my project:

```
+Root folder
 -web.config
 -DataAccess.cs

----+ Ar folder
      -web.config
      -DataAccess.cs
```

connection string for english version (in root web.config)

```
<add name="SqlConnectEng" connectionString="server=MyPc\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=true;database=DbEnglish" />
```

connection string for arabic version (in subfolder ar web.config)

```
<add name="SqlConnectAr" connectionString="server=MyPc\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=true;database=DbArabic" />
```

calling the connection string inside Dataaccess layer:

for Ar folder

```
public static string CONNSTR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnectAr"].ConnectionString;
```

For english version:

```
  public static string CONNSTR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnectEng"].ConnectionString;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Place the connection string in root web.config.

Comment: I did the same with different name. But it still calls the english version.

Comment: No, 
I have dataaccess layer that calls the connectionstring

Comment: Updated the question, please see the it at the end

Comment: You have two Dataaccess layer? root and AR folder?

Comment: Yes, Exactly i have two different dataaccess layer

Comment: Try to debug step by step and see what layer is getting.

Comment: what's up? what is the problem?